# Role of IDL in RPC when programming languages the same on client and server side?

Tags: rpc, idl

Would an IDL (Interface Definition Language) be needed in an RPC (Remote procedure call) even if the programming languages on the client side and the server side are the same (i.e. the function being remotely invoked is written in the same programming language as the program calling the function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the language, whether it has any built-in facility for marshaling arguments and method & object identifiers over the wire. C/C++ has no such support built-in, so we have, for example, MIDL for defining COM interfaces.  Compiling it creates proxy and stub code for converting method call semantics to/from IPC/RPC messaging.

Compiling higher-level languages may produce reflection metadata that's sufficient to generate the marshaling at runtime, so the programming language *is* the IDL.